# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Emacs Stack Exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is using require multiple times on the same symbol idempotent?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8288/is-using-require-multiple-times-on-the-same-symbol-idempotent)

**Net Score: 32** (Excellent: 32, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to change comment string used by comment-region?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7998/how-to-change-comment-string-used-by-comment-region)

**Net Score: 27** (Excellent: 27, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to update frame-title-format and also the current frame title?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/how-to-update-frame-title-format-and-also-the-current-frame-title)

**Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Let statement throws error on assigning a form to a variable](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/let-statement-throws-error-on-assigning-a-form-to-a-variable)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Prevent TTY fallback when X fails](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/prevent-tty-fallback-when-x-fails)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to use helm to complete sources which are lines in a buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9491/how-to-use-helm-to-complete-sources-which-are-lines-in-a-buffer)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Org-mode: Source block doesn't respect parent buffer indentation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9472/org-mode-source-block-doesnt-respect-parent-buffer-indentation)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Trying to enable keybindings for 'outshine': "set before outline-mode is loaded"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8057/outshine-keybindings-set-before-outline-mode-is-loaded)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [How to hide/show graphical emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9789/how-to-hide-show-graphical-emacs)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Emacs wrongly indent else expression in Python code](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8234/emacs-wrongly-indent-else-expression-in-python-code)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 25, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

Comment: 32 people think this "Is using require multiple times on the same symbol idempotent?", but it only got 6 upvotes?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the answer to [my question on lock-files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5967/save-lock-files-to-a-directory-instead-of-disabling-them) is very accurate, plus it answer precisely the questions that I, and possibly many others, have been searching and reformulating for years:

- "How to disable '#' backup files?"
- "How to disable autosave files?"
- "How to change the autosave files directory?"
- "How to change the '#' backup files directory?"

Because people who aren't very familiar with Emacs internals are unlikely to know about lock files, I believe the answer and its title could use some rethinking.

Would it be possible to add the question to the review queue? 
Alternatively are there any recommendations for rewording or extending the question so it ranks higher in google searches?

Comment: The question looks good to me. But for people who don't know what to search for, why not call them "dot-hash" files (in parens)?

Comment: For the future, know that you can always make a post here on meta about stuff like this.